# vbscript asp - Find every Thursday in a given month

Tags: date, vbscript

I'm trying to find all Thursdays within a given Month using VBScript.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Clarify: You want the DATE of all Thursdays within a given month?

Comment: Yes please so in August it would be the following: 4th/11th/18th/25th

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way;

```
base_date = cdate("21 aug 2011")

'get 1st thursday;
thurs = dateserial(year(base_date), month(base_date), 1)
if (weekday(thurs) <> 1) then thurs = 5 - weekday(thurs) + thurs

'loop subsequent;
do until month(thurs) <> month(base_date)
    msgbox thurs
    thurs = dateadd("d", 7, thurs)
loop
```

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you used [Date constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6da89dc2%28VS.85%29.aspx) such as vbThursday and vbSunday instead of magic numbers.

Comment: Approach is over complex for what is a simple task. A `For` loop works just as well with `WeekDay()` function.

Answer (score 0):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255251/692942) does the job it's overly complicated for something that can be accomplished with `WeekDay()` function and a `For` loop.

```
Dim day
Dim startdate: startdate = CDate("21 aug 2011")
Dim enddate
'Get first day of month.
startdate = DateSerial(Year(startdate), Month(startdate), 1)
'Get last day of month.
enddate = DateAdd("m", 1, startdate) - 1
For day = startdate To enddate
  If WeekDay(day) = vbThursday Then WScript.Echo day & " = " & WeekDayName(WeekDay(day))
Next
```

Output:

```
04/08/2011 = Thursday
11/08/2011 = Thursday
18/08/2011 = Thursday
25/08/2011 = Thursday
```

Any [Date and Time constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6da89dc2(v=vs.84).aspx) can be used here to look for different or multiple weekdays with a little tinkering.