# Finding Tuesday for the whole year in ASP Classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

im refereing to this post here.
[vbscript asp - Find every Thursday in a given month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254947/vbscript-asp-find-every-thursday-in-a-given-month/36149786?noredirect=1#comment59937393_36149786)

How im supposed to do it if i wanna find the tuesday for the whole year? let say 2016?

I did try as below based on the code from the post i mentioned above, but it will return me only for August, instead of whole year

```
base_date = cdate("21 aug 2016")

'get 1st thursday;
thurs = dateserial(year(base_date), month(base_date), 1)
'response.write(weekday(thurs))
if (weekday(thurs) <> 1) then thurs = 3 - weekday(thurs) + thurs
'response.write(thurs)
'loop subsequent;
do until month(thurs) <> month(base_date)
    response.write(thurs) 
    response.write("<br />") 
    thurs = dateadd("d", 7, thurs)
loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an overly complicated example, when a `For` loop works just as well with a fixed start and end point.

```
Dim day
Dim startdate : startdate = CDate("22 mar 2015")
Dim enddate : enddate = CDate("22 mar 2016")

For day = startdate To enddate
  If WeekDay(day) = vbTuesday Then Response.Write day & " = Tuesday"
Next
```

Output:

```
24/03/2015 = Tuesday
31/03/2015 = Tuesday
07/04/2015 = Tuesday
14/04/2015 = Tuesday
21/04/2015 = Tuesday
28/04/2015 = Tuesday
05/05/2015 = Tuesday
12/05/2015 = Tuesday
19/05/2015 = Tuesday
26/05/2015 = Tuesday
02/06/2015 = Tuesday
09/06/2015 = Tuesday
16/06/2015 = Tuesday
23/06/2015 = Tuesday
30/06/2015 = Tuesday
07/07/2015 = Tuesday
14/07/2015 = Tuesday
21/07/2015 = Tuesday
28/07/2015 = Tuesday
04/08/2015 = Tuesday
11/08/2015 = Tuesday
18/08/2015 = Tuesday
25/08/2015 = Tuesday
01/09/2015 = Tuesday
08/09/2015 = Tuesday
15/09/2015 = Tuesday
22/09/2015 = Tuesday
29/09/2015 = Tuesday
06/10/2015 = Tuesday
13/10/2015 = Tuesday
20/10/2015 = Tuesday
27/10/2015 = Tuesday
03/11/2015 = Tuesday
10/11/2015 = Tuesday
17/11/2015 = Tuesday
24/11/2015 = Tuesday
01/12/2015 = Tuesday
08/12/2015 = Tuesday
15/12/2015 = Tuesday
22/12/2015 = Tuesday
29/12/2015 = Tuesday
05/01/2016 = Tuesday
12/01/2016 = Tuesday
19/01/2016 = Tuesday
26/01/2016 = Tuesday
02/02/2016 = Tuesday
09/02/2016 = Tuesday
16/02/2016 = Tuesday
23/02/2016 = Tuesday
01/03/2016 = Tuesday
08/03/2016 = Tuesday
15/03/2016 = Tuesday
22/03/2016 = Tuesday
```

You can use any of the valid [Date Time Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6da89dc2(v=vs.84).aspx) here instead of `vbTuesday`.

Comment: Hi Lankymart, thanks a lot. That saves my day a bit. Additionally, what should i amend from your code if wanna display only the first Thursday of each month?

Comment: @HafizK You asked for all the Tuesdays, I'm sure if you analyse it a bit you'll work it out.

Comment: @HafizK Look back [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36151167/692942) I've added an answer that shows how to return all the particular weekday values in a month. You could just using the `If` add `Exit For` once the condition is met this will return you the first occurrence of the weekday in that month.